# Accessing a Javascript prototype function

Tags: javascript, function, input, prototype

I have a prototype function such as event.

**Prototype**

```
Func("input_element_id").event("keyup",function(){
    alert("Works on keyup in an Input!");
}

Func.prototype= {
    keyup: function(func){
         //adding event listener and callback using func
    },
    event: function(e,func) {
         //what to do here to call function "keyup"
    }
};
```

The prototype name is in the variable `e`. But how can i call that `function` using the variable name?

I am doing this, so that passing "keyup keydown" will add keyup and keydown listeners, which is better than calling each prototype function individually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `best way` to achieve this is by:

```
events: function(events,func) {
            this[events](func);
        }
    }
```

Thanks to `CrazyTrain`, As he mentioned in `Comments`.

Comment: So what happened to the spaces?

Comment: @minitech i didnt ask question with adding spaces. I just mentioned why i am doing like this.

Comment: To quote your question, *I am doing this, so that passing "keyup keydown" will add keyup and keydown listeners, which is better than calling each prototype function individually.*. That makes sense… if you just want to add an event by name, instead of making a different function for each one, I’d use `element.addEventListener(singleEventName, func);`. (With appropriate IE compatibility if you’d like.) Making a different function for each one is probably going to be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Func = function(element){
  this.element = element;
};

Func.prototype = {
    keyup: function(handler){
      this.element.onkeyup = handler;
    },
    event: function(e,handler){
        switch(e){
            case 'keyup':
              return this.keyup(handler);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YDekw/

Answer (score 0):

Access the receiving object with `this`.

```
this.keyup(func);
```

Assuming a decent browser or an ES5 shim, looks like you want to do this:

```
e.split(" ").forEach(function(f) {
    this[f](func);
}, this);
```

---

Note that it’s just whatever object is being used with the dot operator, though, and could be anything. For example:

```
var f = new Func("input_element_id");
window.event = f.event;
window.event(); // this is window
```

Comment: `e` is a string representing the property OP wants to access. You should be doing `this[e](func)`

Comment: `.event("keyup",function(){
    alert("Works on keyup in an Input!");
}`

Comment: @Harikrishnan: That won’t work space-separated at all. See update. I was debating whether to add that, but looks like I may as well.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: That’s not going to work if the events are separated by spaces. Which they are. (Or is the ES5 extension the problem? I can change it to a `for` loop if you downvoted because of that. Just guessing at things though since I have no clue.)

Comment: @minitech: Boy did you miss the point. Yes, for space separated words, OP will need to split first. Point is that in the example OP clearly wanted to call the function based on the string. I downvoted because your answer was wrong, I corrected you, and you merely replied with "Nope".

Comment: @minitechi i figured how to do when coming into spaces. But dont know how to access when that is in a variable or when `e` is a string representing the property OP wants to access

Comment: @CrazyTrain: My answer wasn’t wrong. It wasn’t obvious. And you didn’t correct me, because you didn’t split by spaces. You could argue that it was obvious that you needed to split by spaces, and I could argue that it was obvious that you needed to use bracket notation. ***My bad.***

Comment: Your answer was `this.keyup(func);`. You simply failed to read the question. Using `this` was certainly part of the issue though. Either way, your `.forEach()` solution is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks minitech and CrazyTrain

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Maybe I didn’t necessarily understand the question in the same way you did, which is what comments are for, and I would rather an actual helpful comment from the OP instead of what may as well have been your guess at it. And again, if you could explain *why* my `forEach` solution is incorrect instead of just saying that it’s incorrect, kind of like in your first comment, that would be great. ’Course, I can always guess at it too.

Comment: @minitech: Sure, I'll explain. In JavaScript, the `this` value is not lexically defined or inherited. Your `this` in the `.forEach()` will not be the same as that which encloses the callback. To use `this`, you'll need to pass `this` as a second argument to `.forEach()`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Great, I guessed right. For completeness’ sake, `e.split(" ").forEach(f => this[f](func))`.