# Accessing prototype function from another Javascript file keeps returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

I've dug into this for a couple of hours, looking at [Javascript prototype accessing another prototype function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779828/javascript-prototype-accessing-another-prototype-function), [Accessing a Javascript prototype function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773593/accessing-a-javascript-prototype-function), [Trigger one prototype function from another (including itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424559/trigger-one-prototype-function-from-another-including-itself), [Cannot call prototype method from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069026/cannot-call-prototype-method-from-another-function) and around 3-4 other similar questions, and thought "ok, that doesn't seem so bad" and went to implement a solution (or three) to my particular problem.  Or so I had thought!

I have a JS file (compiled from Typescript) that contains an AppComponent class and several methods with it (shortened version focused on my specific trouble follows):

```
AppComponent = (function () {
  function AppComponent() {
    var _this = this;
    this.gridNo = '1';
    //... and so on...
  }
  AppComponent.prototype.MenuSelect = function (link) {
    this.tabCount = 0;
    this.tables = [];
    utils_1.Logging(' MenuSelect: ' + JSON.stringify(link));
    var grids = link.grids;
    this.ws.emit('C:GDRDN', { ds: grids });

    // build up some HTML to make a table of data and return it to
    // the caller
    return "grid stuff!";
  };
.
.
.
}
```

The above is loaded up into Angular 2/Node (written by another co-worker) and works just fine in the context it was written:  ie it displays tables of data ('grids') when called from other components written by that co-worker in TypeScript.

But when I am generating a menu and try to access the MenuSelect prototype directly from another, 'normal', JS file like so...

```
function createWHeelNavigation() {
  basic.navigateFunction = function () {
    var grids_selected = [ 4, 11 ];

    var appcomp = new AppComponent();
    output = appcomp.MenuSelect(grids_selected);

    // minified.js function to add children content to a DOM element
    $("grid_container").add(output);

  }

  // other navigation menu functions...
}

createWHeelNavigation();
```

...I continue to get "Uncaught ReferenceError: AppComponent is not defined" when I click on **that** particular 'basic' menu item, even though according to what I've read in SO and elsewhere that creating a 'new' instance of the object is **the way** to access its prototype methods.

So before I pull my hair out and go back to rocking in the corner of my office, whispering "mommy...", I thought I would pass this around to you fine people to see where I am going wrong.  I have a niggling suspicion I should be using 'this' somewhere, but my eyes are crossing, and wish to be pointed in the right direction.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Could you show us some of your coworker's code that's accessing the `AppComponent`? Is it inside a module perchance? Your issue here isn't with prototypes, it's that you're not accessing the `AppComponent` identifier correctly for one reason or  another.

Comment: Are you using `node.js` and it's `module.exports` system?

Comment: @JLRishe working on digging that out... appears co-worker is using an event handler in an Angular2 HTML template `<md-button (click)="MenuSelect(MItem)" ng-class="{'selected' : MItem === selected }">
` to trigger the function in an older menu system.

Comment: @James111 yes to both!  well technically I'm just working on the front-end at the moment - pure JS and HTML/CSS manipulation, but there is a nodejs server running the show.

Comment: Make sure you are exporting the modules correctly...E.g `module.exports = AppComponent`

Comment: …and moreover, that you are importing the modules correctly in your plain JS code.

Comment: I see 'export' used in various places in the TS code, specifically `export class AppComponent { ...` and everything within that is private except for the MenuSelect function.  And there is complimentary import/export code between the app.component.ts and the original menu.component.ts file, so the data binding is there, and I can confirm that with the older drop-down menu design that 'just works'.  The event listener:  `export class MenuComponent {
  public menuEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); ...` works  with the MenuSelect snippet in the HTML template (mentioned above)

Comment: @Bergi Not sure about your " importing the modules correctly in your plain JS code".  I thought that since all the JS files are loaded, I should be able to access other methods with the techinique I posted, no?

Comment: @JimmPratt: Yes, you can call the *methods* in the way you are doing. But you cannot necessarily access the *constructor* (which is what your error is all about) when it is not a global variable - and the typescript transpilation apparently doesn't make it one.

Answer (score 0):

> I continue to get "Uncaught ReferenceError: AppComponent is not defined" w

A common JavaScript ordering issue. Make sure you are loading your js / ts in the right order.

## More

Please use modules if possible. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

Comment: Appreciate the comment, but file load order does **not** appear to be the issue.  The AppComponent JS file is clearly loaded and spits out a lot of debugging data to the browser console _long_ before I ever click on the menu choice that triggers my code that tries to access the method _in_ AppComponent.

Comment: do you expect it to be on window? if so ... check if it is indeed on window (aka global)

Comment: good point! But here is a silly question:  how would I check for that?  I am confident the menu JS code I wrote is running on window, but not sure how to check the AppComponent codebase.